# Show a message on my datalist while I request my database in angular

Tags: angular

I would like to show a message like "Searching..." while I request my database for some values.

## First version

```
<datalist id="{{row.MYOBJECT}}" >
  <option value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
  <option *ngFor="let i of table[row.MYOBJECT]" value="{{i.MYVALUE}}"> {{i.MYVALUE}}</option>
</datalist>
```

## Edit

```
<ng-template *ngIf="!myBoolean else loading">
  <script>alert("Hello!")</script>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #loading>
  <datalist id="{{row.MYOBJECT}}">
    <option value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let i of table[row.MYOBJECT]" value="{{i.MYVALUE}}">{{i.MYVALUE}}</option>
  </datalist>
</ng-template>
```

How can I manage this ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like loading bar? or div with custom text which will be hide show based on the condition?

Comment: You can create flag for loading, by default it will false until that your searching will be displayed as you get the response, you make that true

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
 <datalist id="{{row.MYOBJECT}}" >
      <option value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
      <option *ngIf="table==null" value="">Searching...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let i of table[row.MYOBJECT]" value="{{i.MYVALUE}}"> {{i.MYVALUE}}</option>
    </datalist>
```

or

```
<span *ngIf="table==null>Searching...</span>
    <datalist id="{{row.MYOBJECT}}" >
      <option value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
      <option *ngFor="let i of table[row.MYOBJECT]" value="{{i.MYVALUE}}"> {{i.MYVALUE}}</option>
    </datalist>
```

Don't forget initialize table with NULL value

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

.ts

```
isSearching:false

getData(){
    this.isSearching = true
    this.service.getData().subscribe(res => {
       this.isSearching = false
    })
}
```

.html

```
<datalist id="{{row.MYOBJECT}}" *ngIf="!isSearching; else searching">
  <option value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
  <option *ngFor="let i of table[row.MYOBJECT]" value="{{i.MYVALUE}}"> {{i.MYVALUE}} 
  </option>
</datalist>

<ng-template #searching>
  <p>Searching...</p>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks. I try like this #edit
It's work when myBoolean is true, but when he's false I can't show my alert.